# Why do we say "kiyay" in karate?

Tags: karate, terminology, kiai

In all of the karate styles I have seen that fighters scream loudly by yelling "kiyay" during kumite when they think that they got a point. I am also a karate student and when I joined my karate classes, my sensei told me to say "kiyay" when we take a point during kumite. I didn't ask him why we say that and so I blindly obeyed what he said. Is yelling "kiyay" an appeal which is made to the referee that we have earn a point in the kumite match?

Comment: The existing answers are very good, however they do not address the fact that the audible kiai is an external expression of the warrior spirit and **should not sound like** 'kiyay'. That is, *kiai* is a Japanese word that has a meaning - you should not shout 'kiaia'!

Comment: I once did that during a grading in front of a japanese examiner, as a naive white belt, to the chagrin of my senpai.